# EntityManager - ManyToMany child entity persistence in Join table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have a `Book` entity with two child entities `Author` and `Genre`, each with a ManyToMany relationship and the corresponding join tables. `Book` class definitions follows:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "book_seq")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "book_seq",
            strategy = "com.example.bookappjpa.dao.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "B"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%08d"),
            })
    private String id;

    @NaturalId
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "rank_no")
    private int rank;

    private int listId;

    private Double rating;

    private int pages;

    private LocalDate publishedOn;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "BOOK_AUTHOR", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
    )
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "BOOK_GENRE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GENRE_ID"))
    private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setRankNo(int rankNo) {
        this.rank = rankNo;
    }

    public void setListId(int listId) {
        this.listId = listId;
    }

    public void setRating(Double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public void setPages(int pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public void setPublishedOn(LocalDate publishedOn) {
        this.publishedOn = publishedOn;
    }

    public boolean addAuthor(Author author) {
        return this.authors.add(author);
    }

    public boolean addGenre(Genre genre) {
        return this.genres.add(genre);
    }

}
```

Persistence method(looking up each entity to by its natural id to see if it already exists in the DB, only proceeding to persist if not. Excuse the half-baked code, yet to improve):

```
 @Transactional
    public void addBook(BookDTO book) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Book b = session.bySimpleNaturalId(Book.class).load(book.getTitle());

        if (null == b) {
            Book bookToDB = new Book();
            bookToDB.setTitle(book.getTitle());
            bookToDB.setPages(book.getPages());
            bookToDB.setRating(book.getRating());
            bookToDB.setRankNo(book.getRank());
            bookToDB.setPublishedOn(book.getPublishedOn());

            book.getAuthors().forEach(a -> {
                Author authorToDB = new Author(a.getName(), a.getAge(), a.getNationality());
                if(null == session.bySimpleNaturalId(Author.class).load(a.getName())) {
                    authorToDB.addBook(bookToDB);
                    entityManager.persist(authorToDB);
                } 
            });

            book.getGenres().forEach(g -> {
                if(null == session.bySimpleNaturalId(Genre.class).load(g.getName())) {
                    Genre genreToDB = new Genre(g.getName());
                    genreToDB.addBook(bookToDB);
                    entityManager.persist(genreToDB);
                }
            });

            entityManager.persist(bookToDB);

        } else {
            String message = "Book with title " + book.getTitle() + " already exists!";
            log.info(message);
            throw new RuntimeException(message);
        }

        session.close();
    }
```

The problem with this approach is, if for instance, a certain book is persisted with a particular `Author` and `Genre`(s), and later on, we have another `Book` with the same `Author` and `Genre`(s), the persistence for the child entities will be skipped as per the code above and nothing populated in the join tables, indicating no relationship between the parent `Book` and child `Author`/`Genre`(s). Should I really be including the check above for the `Author` and `Genre` entities? If not, I'll end up with multiple entities in the corresponding entity tables with the same `Author` and `Genre` name, albeit with different ID sequence numbers(primary key). Not sure if that's good practice. Wanted to know if there's a sophisticated/effii approach to handle such a scenario in Production-grade code. Thanks in advance and apologies if its a rookie question

Two Book objects with the same author(the second one not making it to the join table BOOK_AUTHOR, as the author already exists in DB, and my DAO method will not allow persistence again in such a scenario):

```
{
    "rank": 8,
    "title": "Clap When You Land",
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "Elizabeth Acevedo",
        "age": 0,
        "nationality": null
      }
    ],
    "rating": 0,
    "genres": [
      {

        "name": "Young Adult"
      },
      {

        "name": "Poetry"
      },
      {

        "name": "Contemporary"
      },
      {

        "name": "Fiction"
      },
      {

        "name": "Audiobook"
      },
      {

        "name": "LGBT"
      },
      {

        "name": "Realistic Fiction"
      }
    ],
    "pages": 432,
    "publishedOn": "2020-05-05",
    "listId": 1
  }


{
    "rank": 18,
    "title": "The Poet X",
    "authors": [
      {

        "name": "Elizabeth Acevedo",
        "age": 0,
        "nationality": null
      }
    ],
    "rating": 0,
    "genres": [
      {

        "name": "Poetry"
      },
      {

        "name": "Young Adult"
      },
      {

        "name": "Contemporary"
      },
      {

        "name": "Fiction"
      },
      {

        "name": "Audiobook"
      },
      {

        "name": "Realistic Fiction"
      },
      {

        "name": "Romance"
      }
    ],
    "pages": 368,
    "publishedOn": "2018-03-06",
    "listId": 1
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep relationships consistent and ensure that existing genres and authors are added to new books:

Fetch the genre(s) and author(s) by their natural ids and do the following

- if they exist, add them to book
- if they don't exist,  create them and add them to book

  ```
   book.getAuthors().forEach(a -> {
       Author author = session.bySimpleNaturalId(Author.class).load(a.getName());
       if (author == null) {
           author = new Author(a.getName(), a.getAge(), a.getNationality());
           em.persist(author);
       }
       bookToDB.addAuthor(author);
   });

   book.getGenres().forEach(g -> {
       Genre genre = session.bySimpleNaturalId(Genre.class).load(g.getName());
       if (genre == null) {
           genre = new Genre(g.getName());
           em.persist(genre);
       }
       bookToDB.addGenre(genre);
   });
  ```

Your Genre and Author entities should include the following bidirectional relationship to books

```
@Entity
public class Genre {
...
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres")
   private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
...
}

@Entity
public class Author {
...
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
   private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

and expand your addAuthor(...) and addGenre(...) methods in Book entity to ensure the bidirectional relationship is in sync when you add them

```
@Entity
public class Book {
...
    public boolean addAuthor(Author author) {
        author.getBooks().add(this); // ensures both side of relationship
        return this.authors.add(author);
    }

    public boolean addGenre(Genre genre) {
        genre.getBooks().add(this); // ensures both side of relationship
        return this.genres.add(genre);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, the Author and Genre entities already have the bidirectional relationship in place. Let me try out that approach. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This worked. Thanks again. Should have figured it out but oh well.

Comment: @SoumikBanerjee, glad it's working for you now